# Flash player is not working probably

Tags: flash

Am new at ubuntu. I downloaded flash plugin for my ubuntu, and install it from the terminal but it does not play the movie on YouTube it seams installed, and there is sound and the first picture is there. and when I installed the `libflashplayer.so`, and in terminal i type:

```
          # rah -Uvh libflashplayer.so.
```

I tried several times and it seems installed but those are  not working probably. 
Can some one please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try this
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer